# SQL Convert Rows to Columns to track Job Status

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

SQL Server 2012.  I need to create a query to determine which jobs were in which status at any given date in the past (BONUS: how long they were in that status.)

I have a Job Status Log table with the following columns and structure:

```
JobStatusNo JobNo   Status  Rem         Entered                 EnteredBy
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1644897     420969  801     Reschedule  2017-09-20 17:58:18.503 1488
1644896     420969  812     Cancelled   2017-09-15 08:20:48.390 1267
1644895     420969  803     Confirmed   2017-09-14 10:13:25.733 1231
1644894     420969  802     Call Bob    2017-09-14 09:35:57.337 1231
1644893     420969  801                 2017-09-08 18:18:16.490 1488
1644892     420965  807                 2017-09-20 17:55:02.660 1488
1644891     420965  809                 2017-09-20 17:47:52.340 1488
1644890     420965  806                 2017-09-20 17:40:22.580 1488
1644889     420965  803     Confirmed   2017-09-20 17:05:30.870 1193
1644888     420965  801                 2017-09-20 17:05:29.130 1193
1644877     420964  801                 2017-09-20 17:02:16.830 1193
```

I think I'd like to have a particular job number followed by each status it was in, and when (Plus I don't care about remarks or who entered the job):

```
JobNo   1Status 1Entered                2Status 2Entered                
--------------------------------------------------------------
420969  801     2017-09-20 17:58:18.503 812     2017-09-15.337
420968  801     2017-09-20 17:55:02.660
420967  801     2017-09-20 17:47:52.340
420966  801     2017-09-20 17:40:22.580
420965  803     2017-09-20 17:05:30.870
420965  801     2017-09-20 17:05:29.130
420964  801     2017-09-20 17:02:16.830
```

...with more columns after indicating 3Status and 3Entered, etc.  I only need to code for 8 statuses/entered dates as that's the most number of times a job is reordered or replaced in status.  If there are eventually more columns, I will be able to extend any answer I get here to include that logic.

...because my eventual "answer" will be on July 1st, 2016 (any given date): 87 jobs were in 801 status, 255 jobs were in 806 status and 5 jobs were in 809 status.  In actual fact I need to do math to determine HOW LONG EACH JOB WAS IN A PARTICULAR STATUS eventually, but as this is my first question and I don't know how complicated my answer will be, I'm calling it here as I'm guessing I can figure out the rest once I get these statuses and dates columnar with DateDiff.

I have tried every combination I can think of from UNPIVOT, Lag/Lead, grouping, MAX, et cetera and can get nowhere.

At this point I'm even possibly missing something simple and will feel quite foolish at the answer but I am well and truly stuck.  Am I even going the right way trying to get these columns out of the rows they're currently in?  Is there a way to take the given date and use the table as is?  If anything isn't crystal clear, I will attempt to clarify in updates or answers.  Cheers!

And here's the answer I chose from @Fercstar:

```
WITH A
AS
(
    SELECT
     *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY JobNo ORDER BY Entered DESC) as StatusOrder
    FROM MyJobStatusTable
)

SELECT
 A.JobNo
,A.Status as Status1
,A.Entered as Entered1
,A2.Status as Status2
,A2.Entered as Entered2
,A3.Status as Status3
,A3.Entered as Entered3
,A4.Status as Status4
,A4.Entered as Entered4
,A5.Status as Status5
,A5.Entered as Entered5
,A6.Status as Status6
,A6.Entered as Entered6
,A7.Status as Status7
,A7.Entered as Entered7
,A8.Status as Status8
,A8.Entered as Entered8
,A9.Status as Status9
,A9.Entered as Entered9

FROM A
LEFT JOIN A as A2
    ON A2.JobNo = A.JobNo
    AND A2.StatusOrder = 2
LEFT JOIN A as A3
    ON A3.JobNo = A.JobNo
    AND A3.StatusOrder = 3
LEFT JOIN A as A4
    ON A4.JobNo = A.JobNo
    AND A4.StatusOrder = 4
LEFT JOIN A as A5
    ON A5.JobNo = A.JobNo
    AND A5.StatusOrder = 5
LEFT JOIN A as A6
    ON A6.JobNo = A.JobNo
    AND A6.StatusOrder = 6
LEFT JOIN A as A7
    ON A7.JobNo = A.JobNo
    AND A7.StatusOrder = 7
LEFT JOIN A as A8
    ON A8.JobNo = A.JobNo
    AND A8.StatusOrder = 8
LEFT JOIN A as A9
    ON A9.JobNo = A.JobNo
    AND A9.StatusOrder = 9

WHERE A.StatusOrder = 1
```

Runs in 12 seconds against over a million rows of data with no temp table management required.  ELEGANT!  Thank you @Fercstar.

Comment: Thank you John Cappelletti for the reformat!  Much more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY JobNo ORDER BY Entered DESC)
```

That will get the order of the statuses by job with 1 being the most recent.
You can then pivot by that.

Edit -- Full query based on sample data

```
With A
As
(
Select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY JobNo ORDER BY Entered DESC) as StatusOrder From #Table
)

Select

A.JobNo

,A.Status as Status1

,A.Entered as Entered1

,A2.Status as Status2

,A2.Entered as Entered2

,A3.Status as Status3

,A3.Entered as Entered3

,A4.Status as Status4

,A4.Entered as Entered4

,A5.Status as Status5

,A5.Entered as Entered5

,A6.Status as Status6

,A6.Entered as Entered6

,A7.Status as Status7

,A7.Entered as Entered7

,A8.Status as Status8

,A8.Entered as Entered8

From A
Left Join A as A2
on A2.JobNo = A.JobNo and A2.StatusOrder = 2
Left Join A as A3
on A3.JobNo = A.JobNo and A3.StatusOrder = 3
Left Join A as A4
on A4.JobNo = A.JobNo and A4.StatusOrder = 4
Left Join A as A5
on A5.JobNo = A.JobNo and A5.StatusOrder = 5
Left Join A as A6
on A6.JobNo = A.JobNo and A6.StatusOrder = 6
Left Join A as A7
on A7.JobNo = A.JobNo and A7.StatusOrder = 7
Left Join A as A8
on A8.JobNo = A.JobNo and A8.StatusOrder = 8

Where A.StatusOrder = 1
```

Comment: @DataVis4Fun I updated my answer to include a full query that, using your sample data, returns the desired results. You can calculate the difference between the timestamps if you you want to see how long it was in each status.

Comment: Thank you!  This is compressed, clear and I can follow what you've done and expand on it.  I was able to add additional columns easily and can move on to the math of what was where when.  An elegant and excellent solution to my problem.  I appreciate your time in answering this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a limited num of status you can use it

```
    DECLARE @table table (JobStatusNo int , JobNo   int, Status  int,  Rem  varchar(25) , Entered datetime, EnteredBy int ) 
Insert @table (JobStatusNo ,JobNo   ,Status  ,Rem         ,Entered                 ,EnteredBy) values 
 (1644897     ,420969  ,801     ,'Reschedule'  ,'2017-09-20 17:58:18.503', 1488)
,(1644896     ,420969  ,812     ,'Cancelled'   ,'2017-09-15 08:20:48.390', 1267)
,(1644895     ,420969  ,803     ,'Confirmed'   ,'2017-09-14 10:13:25.733', 1231)
,(1644894     ,420969  ,802     ,'Call Bob '   ,'2017-09-14 09:35:57.337', 1231)
,(1644893     ,420969  ,801     ,'         '   ,'2017-09-08 18:18:16.490', 1488)
,(1644892     ,420968  ,801     ,'         '   ,'2017-09-20 17:55:02.660', 1488)
,(1644891     ,420967  ,801     ,'         '   ,'2017-09-20 17:47:52.340', 1488)
,(1644890     ,420966  ,801     ,'         '   ,'2017-09-20 17:40:22.580', 1488)
,(1644880     ,420965  ,803     ,'Confirmed'   ,'2017-09-20 17:05:30.870', 1193)
,(1644879     ,420965  ,801     ,'         '   ,'2017-09-20 17:05:29.130', 1193)
,(1644877     ,420964  ,801     ,'         '   ,'2017-09-20 17:02:16.830', 1193)


;With CTE as (
SELECT T.JobNo 
,CASE WHEN Substring(CAST ( T.Status as char(3)),2,1) = '0'  THEN T.Status ELSE NULL END [1Status]  
,CASE WHEN Substring(CAST ( T.Status as char(3)),2,1) = '0'  THEN T.Entered ELSE NULL END [1Entered]
,CASE WHEN Substring(CAST ( C.Status as char(3)),2,1) = '1'  THEN C.Status ELSE NULL END [2Status]  
,CASE WHEN Substring(CAST ( C.Status as char(3)),2,1) = '1'  THEN C.Entered ELSE NULL END [2Entered]

from @table t Cross apply (Values(Status , Entered)) C (Status,Entered)
)
SELECT 
JobNo   
,MIN([1Status])  [1Status   ]
,MIN([1Entered]) [1Entered] 
,MAX([2Status ]) [2Status   ]
,MAX([2Entered]) [2Entered]
,Convert(char(8), dateadd(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(Minute,MIN([1Entered]),MAX([2Entered])), ''), 114) StatusTime
FROm Cte
Group By 
JobNo
```

Result

```
JobNo       1Status     1Entered                2Status     2Entered                StatusTime
----------- ----------- ----------------------- ----------- ----------------------- ---------------
420964      801         2017-09-20 17:02:16.830 NULL        NULL                    NULL
420965      801         2017-09-20 17:05:29.130 NULL        NULL                    NULL
420966      801         2017-09-20 17:40:22.580 NULL        NULL                    NULL
420967      801         2017-09-20 17:47:52.340 NULL        NULL                    NULL
420968      801         2017-09-20 17:55:02.660 NULL        NULL                    NULL
420969      801         2017-09-08 18:18:16.490 812         2017-09-15 08:20:48.390 14:02:00
```

Comment: This only works for the first two columns and if they're a specific status...but how do I get the third, fourth, fifth, etc columns of status and entered? I have statuses about which I care of: 806,807,808,809 and 813 with the possibility of any job being in any status first, next or last.  I have 5 statuses and the possibility of each status being used a few times, up to 8 or so columns on the result query.  This doesn't get me out of a hard coding situation which won't work.

Comment: I will create another answer to it.

Answer (score 0):

I did know if it is what you want. I created a code that gets the JobNo and shows all status of it based on the time.

Tables

```
CREATE TABLE ##JobStatusLog  (JobStatusNo int , JobNo   int, Status  int,  Rem  varchar(25) , Entered datetime, EnteredBy int ) 

CREATE TABLE ##tmpJobStatusLog (JobNo   int, Status  int,Entered datetime, Sequence int , StatusName varchar(20) , EnteredName varchar(20))

CREATE TABLE ##StatusSequence(Sequence int, StatusName varchar(20) , EnteredName varchar(20))
```

Data load

```
Insert ##JobStatusLog (JobStatusNo ,JobNo   ,Status  ,Rem         ,Entered                 ,EnteredBy) values 
 (1644897     ,420969  ,801     ,'Reschedule'  ,'2017-09-20 17:58:18.503', 1488)
,(1644896     ,420969  ,812     ,'Cancelled'   ,'2017-09-15 08:20:48.390', 1267)
,(1644895     ,420969  ,803     ,'Confirmed'   ,'2017-09-14 10:13:25.733', 1231)
,(1644894     ,420969  ,802     ,'Call Bob '   ,'2017-09-14 09:35:57.337', 1231)
,(1644893     ,420969  ,801     ,'         '   ,'2017-09-08 18:18:16.490', 1488)
,(1644892     ,420968  ,801     ,'         '   ,'2017-09-20 17:55:02.660', 1488)
,(1644891     ,420967  ,801     ,'         '   ,'2017-09-20 17:47:52.340', 1488)
,(1644890     ,420966  ,801     ,'         '   ,'2017-09-20 17:40:22.580', 1488)
,(1644880     ,420965  ,803     ,'Confirmed'   ,'2017-09-20 17:05:30.870', 1193)
,(1644879     ,420965  ,801     ,'         '   ,'2017-09-20 17:05:29.130', 1193)
,(1644877     ,420964  ,801     ,'         '   ,'2017-09-20 17:02:16.830', 1193)
```

Preparing the data

```
;WITH CTE
AS 
(
SELECT 
* 
, Sequence = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY JobNo ORDER BY  Entered)
FROM 
##JobStatusLog
)
INSERT ##tmpJobStatusLog 
SELECT JobNo   , Status  ,Entered , Sequence , 'Status' + CAST(Sequence as varchar(9))  StatusName , 'Entered' + CAST(Sequence as varchar(9)) EnteredName 
FROM CTE ORDER BY Status
```

Preparing the column names

```
INSERT ##StatusSequence
SELECT DISTINCT Sequence ,StatusName, EnteredName FROM ##tmpJobStatusLog

declare @sql nvarchar(max) =''
declare @columnsStatus nvarchar(max) =''
declare @columnsEntered nvarchar(max) =''
declare @columnsFinal nvarchar(max) =''

Select @columnsStatus = @columnsStatus + N'[' + StatusName + N'],' from ##StatusSequence
Select @columnsEntered = @columnsEntered + N'[' + EnteredName + N'],' from ##StatusSequence
Select @columnsFinal = @columnsFinal + N'[' + StatusName + N'],' + N'[' + EnteredName + N'],' 
from ##StatusSequence
```

Executing

```
SET  @sql = N';WITH Status AS
(
select JobNo,' +  Left(@columnsStatus, Len(@columnsStatus) - 1) + N' from (
select a.JobNo,b.StatusName,   a.Status  from ##tmpJobStatusLog a left join ##StatusSequence b on a.Sequence = b.Sequence
 ) as St pivot ( max(Status) for StatusName in ( ' +  Left(@columnsStatus, Len(@columnsStatus) - 1) + N') ) pvt),
Entered AS (select JobNo,' +  Left(@columnsEntered, Len(@columnsEntered) - 1) + N' from (
select a.JobNo,b.EnteredName,   a.Entered  from ##tmpJobStatusLog a left join ##StatusSequence b on a.Sequence = b.Sequence
 ) as St pivot ( max(Entered) for EnteredName in ( ' +  Left(@columnsEntered, Len(@columnsEntered) - 1) + N') ) pvt
 )
SELECT A.JobNo ,' + Left(@columnsFinal, Len(@columnsFinal) - 1) + N' FROM 
    Status A
INNER JOIN Entered B
On
A.JobNo = B.JobNo'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Result

```
JobNo       Status1     Entered1                Status2     Entered2                Status3     Entered3                Status4     Entered4                Status5     Entered5
----------- ----------- ----------------------- ----------- ----------------------- ----------- ----------------------- ----------- ----------------------- ----------- -----------------------
420964      801         2017-09-20 17:02:16.830 NULL        NULL                    NULL        NULL                    NULL        NULL                    NULL        NULL
420965      801         2017-09-20 17:05:29.130 803         2017-09-20 17:05:30.870 NULL        NULL                    NULL        NULL                    NULL        NULL
420966      801         2017-09-20 17:40:22.580 NULL        NULL                    NULL        NULL                    NULL        NULL                    NULL        NULL
420967      801         2017-09-20 17:47:52.340 NULL        NULL                    NULL        NULL                    NULL        NULL                    NULL        NULL
420968      801         2017-09-20 17:55:02.660 NULL        NULL                    NULL        NULL                    NULL        NULL                    NULL        NULL
420969      801         2017-09-08 18:18:16.490 802         2017-09-14 09:35:57.337 803         2017-09-14 10:13:25.733 812         2017-09-15 08:20:48.390 801         2017-09-20 17:58:18.503
```

Comment: @DataVis4Fun, this is the new anwser.

Comment: To calculate the data between the status, you need to create something like I did with @columnsFinal

Comment: I like this, but when I set it up in my test environment I get 53 statuses and entered columns while there are only 9 instances in the data.  I've tried using the "final" columns you set, but cannot get the math to work on making only the columns with data show up.  Having said that, I learned a bit by using and modifying your code, so THANK YOU!

Comment: No problem, to get only the last 9 status you can use it ;WITH CTE
AS 
(
SELECT 
* 
, Sequence2 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY JobNo ORDER BY  Entered desc)
FROM 
##JobStatusLog
),
WITH CTE1
AS 
(
SELECT 
* 
, Sequence = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY JobNo ORDER BY  Entered)
FROM 
##JobStatusLog where Sequence2 <=9 
)
INSERT ##tmpJobStatusLog 
SELECT JobNo   , Status  ,Entered , Sequence , 'Status' + CAST(Sequence as varchar(9))  StatusName , 'Entered' + CAST(Sequence as varchar(9)) EnteredName 
FROM CTE ORDER BY Status